# how to solve the linux timer error?

Tags: c, linux, timer

```
#include <features.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

typedef unsigned int uint32;

#define million 1000000L

long duration2ms, duration10ms, duration100ms;
double Task2ms_Raster, Task10ms_Raster, Task100ms_Raster;
timer_t firstTimerID, secondTimerID, thirdTimerID;

void TASK1(Task2ms_Raster) {
    struct timespec start, stop;
    int a, b, c;
    uint32 StartTime, StopTime;
    a=1, b=2, c=3;

    if((StartTime = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start)) == -1) {
        perror("clock gettime");
    }


       a= b+c;
        b = c+a;
        c= a+b;

        b = c+a;
        c= a+b; a= b+c;
        b = c+a;
        c= a+b; a= b+c;
        b = c+a;
        c= a+b; a= b+c;
        b = c+a;
        c= a+b; a= b+c;
        b = c+a;
        c= a+b; a= b+c;
        b = c+a;
        c= a+b; a= b+c;
        b = c+a;
        c= a+b;
```

// I did several times like this.

```
    printf("ETAS\n");
    printf("ETAS1\n");
    if((StopTime = clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop)) == -1) {
        perror("clock gettime");
    }
    duration2ms = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) +
                  (double)(stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) /
                  (double)million;
    printf("time difference is= %ld\n", duration2ms);
}

void TASK2(Task10ms_Raster) {
    struct timespec start, stop;
    if(clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start) == -1) {
        perror("clock gettime");
    }
    printf("ETAS2\n");
    printf("ETAS3\n");
    if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop) == -1) {
        perror("clock gettime");
    }
    duration10ms = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) +
                   (double)( stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) /
                   (double)million;
    printf("time difference is= %ld\n", duration10ms);
}

void TASK3(Task100ms_Raster) {
    struct timespec start, stop;
    if(clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start) == -1) {
        perror("clock gettime");
    }
    printf("ETAS4\n");
    printf("ETAS5\n");
    if((clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop)) == -1) {
        perror("clock gettime");
    }
    duration100ms = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) +
                    (double)(stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) /
                    (double)million;
    printf( "time difference is= %ld\n", duration100ms );
}

static void timerHandler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc) {
    timer_t *tidp;
    tidp = si->si_value.sival_ptr;
    if (*tidp == firstTimerID)
        TASK1(Task2ms_Raster);
    else if(*tidp == secondTimerID)
        TASK2(Task10ms_Raster);
    else if(*tidp == thirdTimerID)
        TASK3(Task100ms_Raster);
}

static int makeTimer(char *name, 
                     timer_t *timerID, 
                     int expireMS, 
                     int intervalMS) {

    struct sigevent         te;
    struct itimerspec       its;
    struct sigaction        sa;
    int                     sigNo = SIGRTMIN;

    /* Set up signal handler. */
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = timerHandler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    if(sigaction(sigNo, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
    }

    /* Set and enable alarm */
    te.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    te.sigev_signo = sigNo;
    te.sigev_value.sival_ptr = timerID;
    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &te, timerID);

    its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    its.it_interval.tv_nsec = intervalMS * 1000000;
    its.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    its.it_value.tv_nsec = expireMS * 1000000;
    timer_settime(*timerID, 0, &its, NULL);

    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    makeTimer("First Timer", &firstTimerID, 2, 2);   //2ms
    makeTimer("Second Timer", &secondTimerID, 10, 10);    //10ms
    makeTimer("Third Timer", &thirdTimerID, 100, 100);  //100ms
    while(1) {
        sleep(100);
    }
}
```

I created a timer to call the task for every 2ms, 10ms and 100ms. The tasks are just printing the value and calculating the start time and stop time for printing the value. when i run the above program, it is not displaying time difference between the start time and stop time (i.e duration2ms, duration 10ms nd duration100ms). could someone please help me.

Comment: Please format you code properly when posting it to the world.

Comment: I'd also suggest that you make your code example as short and to-the-point as possible. Now you've just pasted unnecessary complex code which does not point out the problem you're having.

Comment: why is it not displaying the difference between the start time and stop time ??

Answer (score 0):

The time difference is going to show zero in all cases because you are measuring the time it takes to print two lines, which is very fast. You are *not* timing the time between invocations of each task.

If you want to measure the time between invocations of the task, you need to preserve the time. As an example, I'll show one task:

```
void TASK3(Task100ms_Raster) {
     static struct timespec start, stop = { .tv_sec = -1 }; // static duration!
     if (stop.tv_sec < 0) {
        (void) clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop); // first time run
     }
     start = stop; // start from previous stop time

     // do whatever here

     (void) clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop);

     duration100ms = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec)
                     + (double)(stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)
                     / (double)million;
     printf( "time difference is= %ld\n", duration100ms );
}
```

Comment: where are you calculating the start time ?

Comment: @user3340661 `start = stop` where `stop` is the previous stop time (or the current time on the first run). (Note the `static` duration in difference to your code.)

Comment: thank you!!! but why are you specifying the static duration ?? I did not understand that !! on what basis are you specifying it as -1 (.tv_sec = -1)

Comment: `static` keeps the values between invocations of the function, whereas the default automatic duration erases them between runs. (Actually only `stop` needs to be `static` in the example as shown.)

Comment: how to print the start time and stop time in the above code ??

Comment: I want to know the time when it starts executing some functions like printf or something else. stop time of it and also the difference between the start time and stop time.

Comment: @user3340661 Then your code was already correct, but the `printf` calls are so quick that at millisecond granularity the times will be 0.

Comment: I added some code between that and check it then also it is showing error

Comment: @user3340661 What code did you add, where, what error, what do you expect it to show, and what is it showing instead? (Please edit the question.)

Comment: i did some computation but why is it showing minus sign with values ?

Comment: @user3340661 I have no idea because I don't know what "some computation" you did.

Comment: just some addition, subtraction for thirty times but time difference is in negative values.

Comment: Please understand that no-one can help you without seeing the code; edit the question as to show the exact code you are using, and describe what you think it should do, and what it does instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't save your timing values in TASK*() anywhere. This means clock_gettime() gets called twice in a row, having little or no time spent in between. What you should do is something along the lines of following:

```
#include <features.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

typedef unsigned int uint32;
timer_t tmr;
struct timespec prev;

static void handle_timer(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc) {
  timer_t *tidp;
  struct timespec current;

  tidp = si->si_value.sival_ptr;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &current);
  printf("dif between calls to handle_timer: %ld\n",
    current.tv_sec - prev.tv_sec);
  prev = current;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct sigevent se;
  struct itimerspec       its;
  struct sigaction        sa;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &prev);

  /* Set up signal handler. */
  sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
  sa.sa_sigaction = handle_timer;
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  if (sigaction(SIGRTMIN, &sa, NULL) == -1)
    perror("sigaction");

  /* Set and enable alarm */
  se.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
  se.sigev_signo = SIGRTMIN;
  se.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &tmr;
  timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &se, &tmr);

  its.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
  its.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
  its.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
  timer_settime(&tmr, 0, &its, NULL);

  while(1)
    sleep(100);
  return 0;
}
```

The difference here is that we're actually saving the time when handle_time() was called and then calculating the difference against the saved time.

Comment: I want to calculate the time it takes when start executing within the function. dont want to calculate the time from calling the specific task.